# Find a cartesian equation for the polar curve

Tags: parametric

given $r= 9 \tan(\theta)\sec(\theta)$

quite clearly we can do simple trig identities and make this much simpler to work with:

Since:

$\tan(\theta)= \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}$ and $\sec(\theta)= \frac{1}{\cos(\theta)}$

Using $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$, we get:

$r=9\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)} \times \frac{1}{\cos(\theta)}$

Using substitution we get:

$r = 9\frac{\frac{x}{r}}{\frac{x}{r}} \times \frac{r}{x}$

which makes out to be...$1 = \frac{9}{x}$ which is not a parabola

Comment: You made a calculation mistake in the substitution: $\sin(\theta)=\frac{y}{r}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$r= 9 \tan(\theta)\sec(\theta)=9\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos ^2\theta}$$
multiply by $r$
$$r^2=9r\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos ^2\theta}$$
$$r^2\cos^2\theta=9r\sin\theta$$
$$x^2=9y$$

Answer (score 0):

*Variant:*
$$r=9\frac{\tan\theta}{\cos\theta}\implies r\cos\theta=9\tan\theta\iff x=9\frac yx\implies y=\frac{x^2}9.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$r= 9 \tan(\theta)\sec(\theta) , \quad r=9 \tan(\theta)/\cos(\theta)$$

$$r\cos(\theta)=  x = 9 \tan(\theta) = 9 \, y/x $$

$$ 9 y = x^2 $$